# Bash check if any tar.gz file exists in dir

Tags: linux, bash, file, terminal, io

I want to run a set of commands only if there are no tar.gz files in the $DIR. I am trying to do this but the commands execute even when there is no tar.gz file in the path.

```
if [ ! -f "$DIR/*.tar.gz" ]; then { commands; } fi
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: You can't use a wildcard like this in a test

Comment: How can I use the wildcard in this scenario?

Comment: This test for the existence of a file with the literal name `*.tar.gz`. You could for instance create an array containing all files matching the pattern and then check this array. If you follow this apporach, read also in the bash man-page the section describing the option _nullglob_ (in the section _Pathname Expansion_), since the setting of this option influences how you need to test the array.

Comment: `numtars=$(find -maxdepth 1 -name \*.tar.gz -print -quit | wc -l)`

Comment: Get the number of *.tar.gz files first and then go for the if/else structure. For example; ifexists=$(find . -name \*.tar.gz | wc -l); if [[ $ifexists -eq 0 ]]; then echo "yes"; #do your thing here; else echo $ifexists;fi